# Does Android still support Quick Search Box integration?

Tags: android, quick-search, android-app-indexing

I read some information about Quick Search Box and downloaded the [SearchableDictionary sample](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SearchableDictionary) to understand how to make app content available in the global search. When I deploy the app to my phone (Android M) it does not show in the selection list in the 'Phone Search' settings.

1. **[[ANSWERED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641902/is-global-search-in-android-still-available-for-developer)** Is QSB support officially dead? I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932002/how-do-i-get-my-app-to-appear-in-google-nows-phone-search-list) but the answer is old and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001979/global-search-not-working-as-expected-in-android-4-4?lq=1) suggests App Indexing replaces it.
2. How do the two compare?

Answer (score 2):

After more searching I see that [this post confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641902/is-global-search-in-android-still-available-for-developer) that global search is no longer supported for phones/tablets but still exists for Android TV.